# How to compute the target for double Q-learning update step?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl, double-dqn

I've already read the original paper about double DQN but I do not find a clear and practical explanation of how the target $y$ is computed, so here's how I interpreted the method (let's say I have 3 possible actions (1,2,3)):

1. For each experience $e_{j}=(s_{j},a_{j},r_{j},s_{j+1})$ of the mini-batch (consider an experience where $a_{j}=2$) I compute the output through the main network in the state $s_{j+1}$, so I obtain 3 values.
2. I look which of the three is the highest so: $a^*=arg\max_{a}Q(s_{j+1},a)$, let's say $a^*=1$
3. I use the target network to compute the value in $a^*=1$ , so  $Q_{target}(s_{j+1},1)$
4. I use the value at point 3 to substitute the value in the target vector associeted with the known action $a_{j}=2$, so: $Q_{target}(s_{j+1},2)\leftarrow r_{j}+\gamma Q_{target}(s_{j+1},1)$, while $Q_{target}(s_{j+1},1)$ and $Q_{target}(s_{j+1},3)$, which complete the target vector $y$, remain the same.

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$$Y_{t}^{\text {DoubleDQN }} \equiv R_{t+1}+\gamma Q\left(S_{t+1}, \underset{a}{\operatorname{argmax}} Q\left(S_{t+1}, a ; \boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}\right), \boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}^{-}\right)$$

The only difference between the "original" DQN and this one is that you use your $Q_\text{est}$ with the next state to get your action (by choosing the action with the highest Q).

Afterward, you just figure out what the target $Q$ is given that action, by selecting the $Q$ belonging to that action from the target_network (instead of using the argmax a directly on the target Q network).

About the formula

- $\theta_{t}^{-}$ above it means frozen weights, so it represents the *target Q network*.
- the other $\theta_{t}$ represents the "learnable weights" so the *estimate Q network*.

Comment: Yes of course, but the question is quite different, maybe I've not explained well. Try look at this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306921/how-to-update-network-weights-in-dqn

Comment: In other words, "to construct a target vector" do I have to use the target network or the main network?

Comment: Your Q target vector that you want to converge to is the same as your output vector except for the Q at the index of the chosen action, that one is the Y_doubleDQN value described in the paper.